# Why swiper not working when change layout to responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the same problem with demo: https://codepen.io/codenowa/pen/rNVyjGK 
Why change layout to reponsive mode (chrome) and don't reload page, Swiper cannot drag?

```
mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        loop: false,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        width : sizeImg,
        swipe: true,
        watchOverflow:true,
        preventClicks : false,
        preventClicksPropagation : false,
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
          },
        //And if we need scrollbar
        scrollbar: {
            el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
            draggable: true,
        },
         on: {
            sliderMove: function () {
                $.sidr('close', 'sidr');
            },
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this version

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.1.0/js/swiper.js
```

sample in codepen:

```
https://codepen.io/dnjstlr555/pen/qpwRyG
```

Comment: Thank you, but It's correct when you begin at PC layout and change to responsive. When I begin at responsive and change to PC layout, it cannot drag